# How to check if value is equal to container ID in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to check if a property is equal to the ID of a div container.
And add a condition to show the container when the check is equal.

In this example below, I just want to check if the `activeWindow` property is the same as the div id. When it's equal then I want to show the div container.

I have tried to add `id` in the if check, but that didn't work.
When I add the string directly in the if check, like:

`v-if="activeWindow === activeWindow"`

then it works, but this time I have defined the ID at two places and it's not dynamic.

```
private activeWindow = 'activeWindow';

<div v-if="activeWindow === id" id="activeWindow">
 <h1>This window is active</h1>
</div>
<div v-if="activeWindow === id" id="activeWindow1">
  <h1>This window is active</h1>
</div>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The `id` in the if expression is not the `id` attribute, you need to add it as a prop, or get it from a refence of the element etc.

Comment: surely it's `v-if="activeWindow === 'activeWindow'"` since a variable will always be equal to itself (in most cases)

Comment: @JaromandaX but in this case, I have defined the ID at two places as I stated in my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can also bind id and make it both dynamic:

```
<div v-if="activeWindow === id" :id="id">
 <h1>This window is active</h1>
</div>
```

in data function:

```
data() {
  return {
    id: 'active',
    activeWindow : 'active'
  }
}
```

Comment: But I have multiple div containers with all unique ID's. If I define it like this in the data function, then it will not work for the other containers.

Comment: @Can hey mate, that was just example, of course you need to pass id to every container